# Solve this ArrayOutOfBoundException

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner; public class Askisi1 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner ch=new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String[] onomata= new String[6];
    int[] pontoi1=new int[10];
    int[] pontoi2=new int[10];
    int[][] pontoi=new int [6][10];

    int i,k;


        for (i=0; i<onomata.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.println("Parakalw doste to onoma tou"+" " +(i+1)+"ou"+" "+"ipopsifiou!");
            onomata[i] =  ch.nextLine();

        }

        for (i=0; i<=9; i++)
        {
            for (k=0; k<=5; k++)
            {
                System.out.println("Parakalw doste tous pontous tou"+" " +(i+1)+"ou"+" "+"ipopsifiou ston"+" " +(k+1)+"o"+" "+"agwna!!");
                pontoi[i][k]=in.nextInt();
            }
        }

        pontoi1=total1(pontoi);
        pontoi2=total2(pontoi);

        for (i=0; i<=9; i++)
        {
            System.out.println("Oi pontoi tou"+" "+i+1+"ipopsifiou einai"+pontoi1[i]);
        }

        for (i=0; i<=9; i++)
        {
            System.out.println("Oi pontoi tis"+" "+i+1+" "+"s"+"ipopsifiou einai"+pontoi2[i]);
        }

}

        public static int[] total1 (int[][] array) {


                int total = 0;
                int z=0; int j=0;
                int[] a=new int[10];
                for (z=0; z<=5; z++)
                {
                    for (j=0; j<=9; j++)
                    {
                        total=total+array[z][j];
                    }
                    a[z]=total; 
                }

                return a;
            }


    public static int[] total2 (int[][] array) {
                int total2 = 0; int total3=0;
                int z=0; int j=0;
                int[] b=new int[10];
                for (z=0; z<=5; z++)
                {
                    for (j=0; j<=9; j++)
                    {
                        total2=total2+array[z][j];
                    }
                    total3=total3+total2+array[z][j];
                    b[z]=total3;
                }


                return b;
            }
```

}

Hello everyone!

As the compilation is fine without finding any mistakes, in the second loop the programm stops on its own saying this: "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArayIndexOutOfBoundsException:6 at Askisi.main

Sorry for the code, but most of the variables and text is are in greeklish!!
Thanks in advance for any help! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your nested `for` loops, the indexes are backwards.  You've declared `pontoi` as `int[][] pontoi=new int [6][10];`, so the first index ranges from `0` to `5` and the second index ranges from `0` to `9`.  Change

```
pontoi[i][k]=in.nextInt();
```

to

```
pontoi[k][i]=in.nextInt();
```

Answer (score 1):

`int[][] pontoi=new int [6][10];`
and in your nested loop

`for (i=0; i<=9; i++)
        {
            for (k=0; k<=5; k++)
            {
                System.out.println("Parakalw doste tous pontous tou"+" " +(i+1)+"ou"+" "+"ipopsifiou ston"+" " +(k+1)+"o"+" "+"agwna!!");
                pontoi[i][k]=in.nextInt();
            }
        }`
 //i=0 to 9 and k=0 to 5 but at max you can manipulate pontoi[5][9], and you are getting bound exception at pontoi[i=6][k],